# how to make uilabel in uitableviewcell wrap relative to device based on adaptive layout and storyboards

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, adaptive-layout

I have the following `UITableViewController` in my storyboard:

[image]

When I run in the simulator, it cuts off the paragraph in the bottom uilabel and looks like this:

[image]

How can I get the label to stay inside the `uitableviewcell` based on adaptive layout and storyboards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I solve it with the auto layout.

Follow this tutorial in [link](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/) that you will get your problem solved.